# Replace characters except certain strings with gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to replace characters in a column that do **not** match the pattern in a `gsub` function.

data column:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(partij_kort = c("COMBGB", "VVD", "GL", "NIEUWEL", 
"CDA")), .Names = "partij_kort", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

  partij_kort
  <chr>      
1 COMBGB     
2 VVD        
3 GL         
4 NIEUWEL    
5 CDA
```

This code does the opposite what I want:

```
df %>% mutate(new = gsub("VVD|GL|CDA|CU|D66|PVDA|CUSGP|SGP|PVDAGL",
                         "something",
                         partij_kort))

  partij_kort new      
  <chr>       <chr>    
1 COMBGB      COMBGB   
2 VVD         something
3 GL          something
4 NIEUWEL     NIEUWEL  
5 CDA         something
```

I want every string that's **not** in that pattern (`COMBGB` and `NIEUWEL`) to change in `something`.

But the exclamtion mark `!` doesn't work with gsub (I use it a lot with grepl).

Desired outcome:

```
  partij_kort new      
  <chr>       <chr>    
1 COMBGB      something
2 VVD         VVD      
3 GL          GL       
4 NIEUWEL     something
5 CDA         CDA
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Try `"^(?!(?:VVD|GL|CDA|CU|D66|PVDA|CUSGP|SGP|PVDAGL)$).*"` and add `perl=TRUE` to the `gsub` call as the last argument. It will work if you need to replace any value other than the alternative words in your list. I just doubt it is the best way.

Comment: Or combine `,invert = TRUE` with `grep` or `!` with `grepl`

Comment: Within the gsub function? Could you perhaps elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Can `partij_kort` contain `SGP ABC` value? If yes, what is the expected result in `new` column?

Comment: I just added my desired outcome in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no regex is needed, imo:

```
library(dplyr)

exceptions <- c("VVD","GL","CDA","CU","D66","PVDA","CUSGP","SGP","PVDAGL")

df %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(!(partij_kort %in% exceptions), 
                       "something", 
                       partij_kort))
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  partij_kort new      
  <chr>       <chr>    
1 COMBGB      something
2 VVD         VVD      
3 GL          GL       
4 NIEUWEL     something
5 CDA         CDA
```

Comment: Problem is that I want to select on these strings: `"VVD|GL|CDA|CU|D66|PVDA|CUSGP|SGP|PVDAGL"` (those are the exeptions) then every string which is not one of those I want to change in `something`. My example is a small example of multiple strings in `partij_kort`. Can I do `if_else(!partij_kort %in% excepetions, "something", partij_kort))`

Comment: Ah Thanks! If you change your answer that better suits the question (so with the different strings and the `!` mark) I can accept your answer!

Comment: @Tdebeus: Done that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use perl=TRUE in gsub and a regex negating your selection.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(partij_kort = c("COMBGB", "VVD", "GL", "NIEUWEL", "CDA", "anything", "good" ,"bad","whtever")), 
                .Names = "partij_kort", 
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>% mutate(new = gsub("^((?!(VVD|GL|CDA|CU|D66|PVDA|CUSGP|SGP|PVDAGL)).)*$",
                         "something", partij_kort, perl = TRUE))


# A tibble: 9 x 2
  partij_kort new      
  <chr>       <chr>    
1 COMBGB      something
2 VVD         VVD      
3 GL          GL       
4 NIEUWEL     something
5 CDA         CDA      
6 anything    something
7 good        something
8 bad         something
9 whtever     something
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replace` with `grepl` like below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(new = replace(partij_kort , !grepl("VVD|GL|CDA|CU|D66|PVDA|CUSGP|SGP|PVDAGL",
                         partij_kort),"something"))


# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  partij_kort       new
#        <chr>     <chr>
#1      COMBGB something
#2         VVD       VVD
#3          GL        GL
#4     NIEUWEL something
#5         CDA       CDA
```